# How does the Google Play signing certificate looks like

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Since some time it is possible to opt in for Application to be signed with Google maintained key. How does the certificate looks like? Is it a self signed one like before, or maybe it is issued from some Google one?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the applications signed by Google is simple that you upload your private key + certificate and Google then performs the signing instead of the app developer. The certificate and the created signature is identical to the one created by a developer.

I would assume that Google introduced this feature because a lot of developers loos their app signing keys and are then unable to publish updates for an existing app.

Comment: Looks like there's a possibility that if the developer doesn't provide their own the signing key, then [it will be generated by Google and cannot be downloaded](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#app-signing-google-play). I guess the question asks for the automatically generated one.

Comment: @AndrewT From my understanding this is just a convenience functionality so that the developer does not have to generate a private key and then upload it to Google. As already all apps provided in the Google PlayStore are additionally signed by Google (aka ["frosted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090841)) it is just not necessary to change something in the app signing key generation process when it runs in the Google cloud.

Comment: @Robert the question is about the certificate used by google to sign the app, is it self signed or maybe there is some trust path to check if it is a google cert

Comment: @majkrzak I had access to a large pool of popular Android apps from the last year (~12k apps) and I checked all of them for their signature using apksigner. Most apps have a single self-signed certificate. Only a few apps from Microsoft and Amazon use a certificate chain, but only the leaf cert is included. Not a single app used a root-cert of Google. I would assume that at least a few apps of those 12k have their cert generated by Google. Therefore I think we can take it for sure that the Google generated certs are no different to the user generated.

Answer (score 1):

It is RSA 4096 self signed certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            ...
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc., OU = Android, CN = Android
        Validity
            Not Before: ... 2020 GMT
            Not After : ... 2050 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc., OU = Android, CN = Android
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
```

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more. Just pasting a certificate dump is not a good answer.

Comment: @Robert I'm not really sure what should I add there (ok for sure where those cert comes form: it was generated yesterday for the new app using google console) Can you merge my "answer" into yours, It seems im not the best in selfanswering

Comment: Well first you should briefly describe what you did and that the presented certificate has been generated via Google by you (my assumption).